# Why the following WPF style is not applied?

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

Why doesn't the following style work? I have in other places the exact same construct with different controls and it works.

Using `TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"` instead of `TargetType="Separator"` doesn't work either. Neither moving `Style` upper in the XAML hierarchy. Can I avoid using `x:Key="styleName"` and `Style="{StaticResource styleName}"`?

But more importantly I'm trying to understand why such a style binding doesn't work always.

```
<ToolBar Height="25">
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Separator">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </ToolBar.Resources>

    <RadioButton Content="A"/>  <!-- NOT APPLIED HERE -->
    <Separator/>                <!-- NOT APPLIED HERE -->
    <RadioButton Content="B"/>  <!-- NOT APPLIED HERE -->
</ToolBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF's Toolbar does some funky things with its child controls. Unlike other containers, it's not as simple as defining a style that applies to a type.

Have a look at this blog post for some information that might help. [Styling controls on a ToolBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsdk/styling-controls-on-a-toolbar).

Comment: Excellent article on the ToolBar. Thanks for the link!